# Display of Bitmap images using Apache fop 2.1

Tags: xslt, bitmap, apache-fop

I have been creating a XSL template to use with Apache FOP 2.1. I have written a simple Java program which is called as a standalone jar and when run will generate a PDF document based on the XSL template and an input XML document. The input document is an XML file which contains various responses including strings  and also images (bitmaps and jpegs) stored as base 64 strings. I have been able to produce a PDF which include jpegs but when I attempt to display a bitmap the image is displayed upside down and reversed (mirror image). I have taken the base 64 string from the input and placed it in an `<IMG>` tag in simple HTML page and the bitmap is displayed in the correct orientation so I am wondering if this is a feature of Apache FOP and if so is there a way of manipulating the image so it displays correctly for me?

I have been able to rotate the bitmap image with the following code but so far have not found a way of producing a mirror version of the image:

```
<!-- Response Template - Bitmap -->  
<xsl:template name="ResponseBitmap">
  <xsl:param name="ResponseItem" /> 
    <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="solidBorder" width="5.26cm" height="7.73cm">
        <fo:block-container reference-orientation="180" width="5.26cm" height="-2.29cm">
            <fo:block>
                <fo:external-graphic width="100%" 
                 content-height="100%" content-width="scale-to-fit" scaling="uniform"
                                     src="data:image/bmp;base64,{$ResponseItem}" /> 
            </fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
    </fo:table-cell>   
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Are all bitmap images incorrectly displayed, or just a specific one?

Comment: In my example I have two different bitmaps and both are consistently displayed up side down and as a mirror image.